LambdaTest CloudTesting App Automation using APN
So in our company we have private provider for SIM Cards and is also providing us APN for more secured data flows. Until now, we have been using physical devices and maintaining them on our own in our internal site. I would love to move on from this, so I am now trying to setup LambdaTest in our environment.
I am using their tunnel which is working just fine with accessing our private domains.
What is NOT working is an App that is using APN. This is the screen
and this is the error
I've been also replied from LambdaTest support this

The APN settings you provided are specific to your SIM provider and won’t function on the LambdaTest platform.

so you mean there is no way for an App that is using APN to use CloudTesting platforms? I hope anyone has an answer for this.
Thank you
